# Brightness control on a desktop PC

Tags: brightness, 22.04

I have an Aerofara Aero Pro 2, a desktop mini-PC with Intel N5105 CPU. After upgrading from Ubuntu 21.10 to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I noticed that in the top right menu there's a "Brightness" control that does nothing (since I'm not on a laptop). Is this expected? Or should I file a bug report?

Maybe unrelated but now I also have "power management" profiles (performance, balanced and power saver) is this expected on a desktop PC?

Comment: Power management profiles are indeed expected regardless of the machine type as long as such feature is supported by the hardware. The brightness typically only appears in laptops or similar with an internal screen.

Comment: Ok, then I'll just keep power options to "Performance". Regarding brightness, is there a way to check how Ubuntu thought I had a brightness control on my computer?